# How to export paragraphs in one line using Apache Tika

Tags: parsing, apache-tika, tika-server

I am passing a PDF document to the Apache Tika software, which is in this format:

PDF document with paragraphs like these:

```
(iii) 50% of Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text. 

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 1 Text Text Text Text Text 
Text Text.
```

I am getting the text in the same format as the input text provided in the PDF file.

But the output expected is :

```
(iii) 50% of Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. 

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 1 Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
```

I want to export the paragraphs in one line rather than in the same format as provided in the input file.

I am making the call to Tika in this way:

```
private Tika tika = new Tika();
String content = tika.parseToString(file);
```

I receive the content of the file in the content variable.

Is there any configuration through which I can make this happen?

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Ask Apache Tika for the XHTML version instead of plain text, then split yourself by `<p>` tags?

Comment: @Gagravarr, is there a way that I can extract all the text present inside the <p> tags one by one?

Comment: A quick-and-dirty solution would probably be just to split on a regexp based on the tags... "proper" solution is to write a custom ContentHandler, pass that to Tika, and have that route the text into chunks by paragraph tag